# calling set on destroyed object setInterval in acceptance tests

Tags: ember.js

I know that there are like 5 topics with the same name here, but they seems to be unrelated to my case: I'm getting this error in acceptance tests, and the reason for that is the countdown component built with Ember.run.later.

Maybe someone know how to cure that?

Comment: I'm sure somebody does know. Does that answer your question?

Comment: yup (Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.)

Answer (score 0):

Just should stop timer upon element destruction. Ember, of course, doesn't handle that by himself.

```
startCountdown: function() {
  let handler;
  //...

  handler = setInterval(...);
  this.set('handler', handler);
}

  teardown: function() {
    clearInterval(this.get('handler'));
  }.on('willDestroyElement')
```